# Plotting Large Bipartite Graphs in R with igraph

Tags: r, igraph, graph-visualization

I'm working with a large number of nodes in a bipartite graph.  I'm using the `igraph` package.  But the result is too dense:

[image]

Here is the R code that generates the graph:

```
library(igraph)
rd<-read.csv("bipartite-sna.csv")
g <- graph.data.frame(rd, directed=TRUE)
V(g)$type<-V(g)$name %in% rd[,1]
png("bipartite.png", width=1200, height=400)
shape<-c("circle","square")
plot(g, layout=layout.bipartite, vertex.shape=shape[as.numeric(V(g)$type)+1], vertex.label=NA)
vertex.size=7, rescale=TRUE)
dev.off()
```

Apparently just ratcheting up the size of the output doesn't cause the nodes to automatically spread themselves out.  What should I be adjusting in order to improve the legibility of the graph?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a reproducible example. This will give people who want to help you something to work with and to test. 
You can read about it **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)**. In the above case, I miss data to play with.

Comment: How many nodes do you have in each layer?

Comment: There are 36,698 nodes in the top partition and 334 in the bottom partition.

Comment: Even for the smaller bottom, it is not reasonable to expect to see 364 distinct nodes in a single, horizontal line, but you are not going to be able to space out 36,698 nodes on the full two dimensions and see anything.